# How do I fix an "Unable to create directory" error when I try to upload themes in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I installed WordPress but now I can not install themes. I get this error:

```
Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2015/08. Is its parent directory writable by the server?
```

I have tried changing permissions to wp-content to 755 but did not fix it.

Comment: Have you changed the permission just for `wp-content` or also for all of its subfolders?

Comment: All its sub folders using filezilla option

Comment: And the owner is set to the webserver user (not the ftp user!) ?

Comment: Hmm understand but don't understand last comment

Answer (score 0):

Read [Changing File Permissions « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)

If you can't or don't know how to check or change folder and FTP owners and groups, ask your web host.

> Typically, all files should be owned by your user (ftp) account on
>   your web server, and should be writable by that account. On shared
>   hosts, files should never be owned by the webserver process itself
>   (sometimes this is www, or apache, or nobody user).
>
> Any file that needs write access from WordPress should be owned or
>   group-owned by the user account used by the WordPress (which may be
>   different than the server account). For example, you may have a user
>   account that lets you FTP files back and forth to your server, but
>   your server itself may run using a separate user, in a separate
>   usergroup, such as dhapache or nobody. If WordPress is running as the
>   FTP account, that account needs to have write access, i.e., be the
>   owner of the files, or belong to a group that has write access. In the
>   latter case, that would mean permissions are set more permissively
>   than default (for example, 775 rather than 755 for folders, and 664
>   instead of 644).

Answer (score 0):

Try do add this options to your wp-config.php file

```
define('FS_CHMOD_DIR', (0755 & ~ umask()));
define('FS_CHMOD_FILE', (0644 & ~ umask()));
```

Comment: and what does this do?